# Removing empty lines and duplicate lines from text file

Tags: unix, awk

I recently used the awk command to remove duplicate lines, and spaces between lines but I am not getting the desired output file.

Input file:

```
a b

a b

c d

c d

e f

e f
```

Desired output:(I wanted to remove duplicate lines and all spaces in between lines)

```
a b
c d
e f
```

I used the following code:

```
awk '!x[$0]++' input file > output file
```

And got this output:

```
a b

c d
e f
```

The space between the first line and all the rest is still in the output file.
Help please and thank you.

Comment: Your code is failing, since the empty lines are only removed as duplicates after seeing the first empty line.

Comment: Do you want duplicate lines removed when you have unique lines in between? I mean: do you want to remove a line `a b` when it is the last line in your input file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the original line order of the input is important, then the following will not work for you.  If you don't care about the order, then read on.

For me, awk is not the best tool for this problem.

Since you are trying to use awk, I assume you are in a unix-like environment, so:

When I hear "eliminate blank lines" I think "grep".
When I hear "eliminate duplicate lines" I think "uniq" (which requires sort, though not in your example since it is already sorted.)

So, given a file 'in.txt' that duplicates your example, the following produces the desired output.

```
    grep -v "^[[:space:]]*$" in.txt | uniq
```

Now, if your real data is not sorted, that won't work. Instead use:

```
    grep -v "^[[:space:]]*$" in.txt | sort -u
```

Your output may be in a different order than the input in this case.

Comment: You made my day. Thanks for the gotcha really helped the caviat is [[:space:]]* Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 6):

```
awk 'NF && !seen[$0]++' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

`NF` removes white lines or lines containing only tabs or whitespaces.

`!seen[$0]++` removes duplicates.

Answer (score -2):

```
cat test
```

a b

a b

c d

c d

e f

e f

```
awk '$0 !~ /^[[:space:]]*$/' test
```

a b

a b

c d

c d

e f

e f

Comment: That code could be written as just `awk 'NF' test` but it doesn't answer the OPs question anyway. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35190319/1745001 for the answer.